# What is mysql indexes?

Tags: sql, mysql, indexing

I don't get what is that? It's id which auto increase number?

Comment: Why the downvotes?  I understand the question isn't well formed, but it is still a question someone has.  English isn't everyone's first language (though some people who DO speak English natively post poorly formed questions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An index in a database is an aid to help searching for information within specific columns of a database table.  But while an index helps searching, it also impacts data being inserted, updated and/or deleted.

> It's id which auto increase number?

No, that's not an index - it's a sequence value, used in MySQL so that when you add records to a table, the column value is always unique.  Because the value is unique, searching by it will always return the same, single record.

Answer (score 2):

[General Index Info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index)

Indexes are basically ways for a DB to speed up a search for data.  When you have tons of records it really help to be able to look up certain data from a query faster.  You just have to be aware of how to use them and when they don't work like you might think!

[MySQL Index creation info](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-index.html)

Auto incrementing numbers are a feature you can use to have MySQL generate unique IDs for a column.

[MySQL Auto Increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-auto-increment.html)

Answer (score 0):

And index is a structure that the database server manages which helps it sort and search a table faster.  There are a ton of related concepts you'll want to read up on ([Binary Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree), [Linear searching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_search), lots more) to get up to speed, but start with [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_(database)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_%28database%29) for an overview.